# Python requests fails to get all the links from a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm learning how to use Python `urllib.requests` module and I've been trying to get all the links from the website, although it works for most of them, I'm having trouble opening [this one](https://randomtube.xyz).

The output I'm getting for this link is just:  `# python teosa.py []`

The whole code looks like this:

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request("https://randomtube.xyz/")
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is there are no links in url given.

Your script should work as-is. Try a site with links.

Note: I do not think you need to 'import re'.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import re

req = Request("https://google.com/")
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```

```
['https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi', 'https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl', 'https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8', 'https://www.youtube.com/?gl=US&tab=w1', 'https://news.google.com/?tab=wn', 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm', 'https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo', 'https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh', 'http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en', '/preferences?hl=en', 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.com/&ec=GAZAAQ', '/advanced_search?hl=en&authuser=0', '/intl/en/ads/', '/services/', '/intl/en/about.html', '/intl/en/policies/privacy/', '/intl/en/policies/terms/']
```

Comment: Note: The site you give does have links after script loading is complete and page renders, but it looks like that part of page is "composed" using Javascript - not straight HTML. [See this answer](https:/stackoverflow.com/a/48432940/503621) for more.